# Bash script in cygwin can't find existing file

Tags: bash, docker, cygwin

I wrote a simple bash script to run a `docker-compose` command, trying to run it from any location.

```
path="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
docker-compose -f "$path/docker-compose.yml" -f "$path/docker-compose.$env.yml" up $DETACHED $service
```

I was previously on Windows 10 Home using Docker Toolbox, and on the Docker Terminal, the script ran fine. I upgraded to Win 10 Pro and Docker for Windows, and when I run the script in Cygwin/Babun, I instead get

```
.FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/f/www/phpDM/docker-compose.yml'
```

Problem is, that's exactly where the file is. If I run the command the script is using with that path, it works. I can't seem to figure out what's going on (or how I can utilize a terminal like whatever Docker Terminal used?).

The full script:

```
#!/bin/bash

env="dev"
for opt in $@; do
    parsed=0
    case $opt in
        "-d")
            DETACHED="-d"
            parsed=1
            ;;
        "-e")
            env=$2
            valid=0
            valid_envs=("dev" "prod")
            for valid_env in ${valid_envs[@]}; do
                if [[ $env == $valid_env ]]; then
                    valid=1
                    break
                fi
            done
            if [ $valid == 0 ]; then
                env="dev"
            fi
            shift
            parsed=1
            ;;
    esac

    if [[ $parsed == 1 ]]; then
        shift
    fi
done

if [[ $# == 1 ]]; then
    service=$1
fi

path="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
docker-compose -f "$path/docker-compose.yml" -f "$path/docker-compose.$env.yml" up $DETACHED $service
```

Comment: Can you try with: `docker-compose -f "${path}"/docker-compose.yml -f "${path}"/docker-compose.${env}.yml up "${DETACHED}" "${service}"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Didn't change anything.

Comment: Possible for you to post the entire script ?

Comment: I added the full script above

Comment: Thanks.. and can you post the two commands (1) when you call the script - with arguments (2) The raw command which works directly on terminal

Comment: I'm just running `./run`, and the one that works is `docker-compose -f "/f/www/phpdm/docker-compose.yml" -f "/f/www/phpdm/docker-compose.dev.yml" up`

Comment: Looks like a strange issue. In order to debug this further, I would add a echo "$path" just before running the `docker-compose ...`. Secondly, I'm not sure if windows paths are causing issue here (case senstivity) because the error message above says `phpDM` and your command says `phpdm`

Comment: Sorry, that's my mistake. It's consistent capitalization, I was testing both ways.

Comment: Docker for Windows probably wants to see Windows style directory and file names. Wrap the cygwin directory and file names in `$( cygpath -w "cygwin_name" ) ` in the "docker-compose …" command line. Also, to avoid confusion, rename the "path" variable so it does not differ only by case from "PATH".

Comment: @DougHenderson Thanks for the suggestion; I'll try it. However, if I enter `docker-compose -f "/f/www/phpdm/docker-compose.yml" -f "/f/www/phpdm/docker-compose.dev.yml" up` directly, it works, so it's likely not expecting the path format. And good point, I'll rename the var.

Comment: Try wrapping quotes around `$DETACHED` and `$service` in case either are blank or unset.

Comment: Try prefixing the `docker-compose …` command with `echo` or insert `echo "path = $path"` just before that line (or both) to make sure that $path contains what you expect.

Comment: To make sure that the environment the script is executing in can see the file I'd suggest adding `file "$path/docker-compose.yml"` before the call to docker-compose and seeing if it gives you the same error.